# How can I compare the differences of two arrays and output the key, which only exits in one array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array (`$name_new`) that is created by a text file:

```
foreach ($properties as $key => $row) {
     $name_new[] = $row['name'];    
}
```

Here is the result for `$name_new`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "john"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "frank"
}
```

And another array I am creating from the mySQL database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data;                 
$p = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$p->execute();

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $name_orig[] = $row['name'];
}
```

Here is the result for `$name_orig`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "john"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "sam"
}
```

I am comparing those two arrays:

```
if ($name_new != $name_orig) {
   $name_result = array_diff_assoc($name_orig, $name_new);
   foreach($name_result as $r){
      echo "This name is not matching: ".$r;
   }
}
```

So my result here is:

**This name is not matching: sam**

My problem is, that I would also need the key for the name in my result. But this key only exists in the text file.

So if I write this:

```
foreach ($properties as $key => $row) {
     $name_new[$key] = $row['name'];    
}
```

Here is the result for `$name_new[$key]`...

```
array(2) {
  ["123"]=>
  string(32) "john"
  ["456"]=>
  string(32) "frank"
}
```

... I get the key. But how can I connect this key to my result `sam`

The result I would need is

**This name is not matching sam (Key: 456)**

Answer (score 3):

Please improve below code

```
if ($name_new != $name_orig) {
   $name_result = array_diff_assoc($name_orig, $name_new);
   foreach($name_result as $k=> $r){
      echo "This name is not matching: ".$r." and key:".$k;
   }
}
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

when comparing both arrays, just adding the index along to your foreach loop should do the trick:

```
foreach($name_result as $k => $r){
   echo "This name is not matching: ".$r. "(Key:".$k.")";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in my code, updated it, it should all be `name` not `fileName`

Comment: fixed in my answer, the idea is the same though. The keys are there for you to process, you just have to ask for them.

Comment: I tested your code. My result is: `This name is not matching: sam (Key:1)`

Comment: What I would need is the key from frank

Comment: in that case you'd have to compare arrays the other way round (i.e. call once again `array_diff_assoc` with arguments in reverse order)

Comment: But the problem is, that maybe frank is missing totally. Than I also need the error message that something went wrong with sam